# How to api calls without errors an angular and Php application in web server?

Tags: php, angular8

I am new to web deployment, I already built angular 8 and
 php 7 application and I hosted them. On local all api calls work but
 after deployment errors like status 500 and not even a single api
 call work on TLS server

here some code :

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$email = htmlspecialchars($decoded->email, ENT_QUOTES);
$pass = htmlspecialchars($decoded->password, ENT_QUOTES);
function conn()
{
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "smart";

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=91.134.248.250;dbname=smart', $user,
        $pass);
    return $conn;
}

function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string)
{
    $output = FALSE;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'WS-SERVICE-KEY';
    $secret_iv = 'WS-SERVICE-VALUE';
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv),
        0, 16);
    if($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output =
            base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0,
                $iv));
    } else {
        if($action == 'decrypt') {
            $output =
                openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0,
                    $iv);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

if(empty($email) || empty($pass) || mb_strlen($pass) < 6 || mb_strlen($pass) > 30) {
    json_encode(FALSE);
    die;
} else {
    $db = conn();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $password = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $pass);
    $res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ? ");
    $res->execute([$email, $password]);
    $values = $res->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode(sizeof($values) > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
?>
```

here code of connecter.componet.ts :

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { User } from '../models/user.model';
 import { UserService } from 'app/services/user.service';
 import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
 import { NgxUiLoaderService } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
 import { LocalStorageService } from 'ngx-localstorage';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
 import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
 import { AlertService } from 'ngx-alerts';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-connecter',
 templateUrl: './connecter.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./connecter.component.scss']
 })
 export class ConnecterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 onSubmit() {
 let email = this.AuthForm.get('email').value;
 let password = this.AuthForm.get('password').value;
 let nomcomplet = '';
 let occupation = '';
 let newUser = new User(email, password, nomcomplet, occupation, '');
 console.log(newUser);
 this.httpSubscription = this.http.post("http://www.smartlibrairie.com/SmartLibrary/api/logins.php",

 JSON.stringify(newUser)).subscribe(res => {
 console.log(res);
 if (res === true) {
 this.ngxService.start();
 setTimeout(() => {
 this.ngxService.stop();
 }, 3000);
 if (newUser.email === "admin@gmail.com") {
 this.ngxService.start();
 this.authService.signIn().then(
 () => {
 console.log('Connexion réussite   !');
 this.authStatus = this.authService.isAuth;
 this.ngxService.stop();
 this.router.navigate(['espace-admin']);
 localStorage.setItem('token', "true");
 console.log(this.authStatus);
 }
 );
 localStorage.setItem('session', newUser.email);
 }else {
 this.ngxService.start();
 this.authService.signIn().then(
 () => {
 console.log('Connexion réussite   !');
 this.authStatus = this.authService.isAuth;
 this.ngxService.stop();
 this.router.navigate(['produits']);
 localStorage.setItem('token', "true");
 console.log(this.authStatus);
 }
 );
 //Parse the serialized data back into an aray of objects
 localStorage.setItem('session',newUser.email);
 }
 } else if (res === false){
 this.alertService.danger('Erreur de connexion! Vérifier vos données saisies');
 this.AuthForm.reset();
 }
 });
 }
 }
```

> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQqYs.png

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Do not modify/escape a user's password. You will drastically change the password from what the user wanted. Instead, use [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) when storing it, and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when verifying it.

Comment: i think the problem is on the server rules